# How to extract an object in array in object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to extract data to the HTML table.

When I extract the data from arrays and objects I have the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '12:00' of undefined
    at generateTable (build-table.js:30)
    at build-table.js:38
```

```js
var openingHours = {
  monday: [{ begin: "10:00", end: "12:00"}, { begin: "13:00", end: "18:00"}],
  tuesday: [{ begin: "10:00", end: "12:00"}, { begin: "13:00", end: "18:00"}],
  wednesday: [{ begin: "10:00", end: "12:00"}, { begin: "13:00", end: "18:00"}],
  thirsday: [{ begin: "10:00", end: "12:00"}, { begin: "13:00", end: "18:00"}],
  friday: [],
  saturaday: [],
  sunday: [], 
};

function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
}

function generateTable(table, openingHours) {
  
  var { monday: [{ begin, end }] } = openingHours;
  console.log(begin, end);
  
  for (element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (let key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element.Object[end], (key));
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}

let table = document.querySelector("table");
let data = Object.keys(openingHours);
generateTableHead(table, data);
generateTable(table, openingHours);
```

Comment: Maybe you could clarify your title. Are you trying to generate a HTML table, or a JS array?

Comment: Where did `.Object` come from in `element.Object`? Also, if you want to get the `end` property of something, it’s `element.end`, not `element[end]`. But maybe you meant `element[key]`. `document.createTextNode` only takes one argument. Try to build this in small steps, making sure things are working after each point, so there’s less room for confusion.

Comment: @Jeremie i want to generate a HTML table

Comment: If you want to be sure that "Monday" comes before "Tuesday", consider storing those values in an array not as property names of an object, in which order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Ry- Yes i am going to build this in small steps, thank you :)

Comment: @James This is a little test for a company, i can't change the values x)

Comment: thank you @Lemondoge

Comment: Here's what you're looking for, including ensuring the proper order of days: https://jsfiddle.net/hom50Lrq/ (not posting an answer because "this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers")

Comment: Sorry, apparently I was wrong with my answer - to my surprise, that actually works the way you're doing it. I didn't do thorough enough testing

Comment: Haha that's ok thank you again ! @Lemondoge

Comment: @ChrisG you saved me I thank you very much!